# Remotely accesssing RTSP url with Python & OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am able to view the camera on the local area network with the following python code, not a problem. However when the same code is run from a remote site, it breaks with empty frames. VLC player can view this network address over the remote connection just fine. Here is the code:

> 

```
import os
import cv2

os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"]="rtsp_transport;udp|analyzeduration;2000|"
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_DEBUG"] = "1"
os.environ["OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL"] = "VERBOSE"


x='rtsp://home_routers_ip:cameras_fwded_port/onvif1'  

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(x,cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
       print("Frame is empty")
       break;
    else:
       cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
       if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output from home LAN where it works:

> 

```
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] Starting connection attempt to Home_Router's_IP port 42???
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] Successfully connected to Home_Router's_IP port 42???
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] SDP:
v=0
o=- 1421069297525233 1 IN IP4 192.168.1.21
s=H.264 Video, RtspServer_0.0.0.2
t=0 0
a=tool:RtspServer_0.0.0.2
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:500
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001F;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAH5WoFAFuQA==,aM48gA==
a=control:track1
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
a=control:track2
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000


[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] max_analyze_duration 2000 reached at 20000 microseconds st:1
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:24] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, 1 reference frame, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (2000) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv420p


WORKING! A live camera window opens up.
```

And finally,
output when code is run from a remote site:

> 

```
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] Starting connection attempt to Home_Router's_IP port 42???
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] Successfully connected to Home_Router's_IP port 42???
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] SDP:
v=0
o=- 1421069297525233 1 IN IP4 192.168.1.21
s=H.264 Video, RtspServer_0.0.0.2
t=0 0
a=tool:RtspServer_0.0.0.2
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:500
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001F;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAH5WoFAFuQA==,aM48gA==
a=control:track1
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
a=control:track2
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:40] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[OPENCV:FFMPEG:24] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, 1 reference frame, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (2000) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Frame is empty

PROGRAM Aborts :(
```

Comment: How do you access it with vlc from remote?

Comment: What happens if you `sleep` a bit before reading? It could be that no frame has been captured yet.

Comment: Micka vlc access from remote is no different from local, ctrl/command N and pasting the rtsp url. Kesh, tested adding sleep before reading, no difference.

Comment: The problem seems this line 'o=- 1421069297525233 1 IN IP4 192.168.1.21' A tcpdump output showed 'cap = cv2.VideoCapture(x,cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)' is sending udp datagrams to 192.168.1.21 (instead of the home_routers_ip:cameras_fwded_port), which happens to be the rtsp servers address on local LAN. All good if accessing from local LAN but remotely it's meaningless.

Comment: Thats because its using rtsp/rtp/udp Change Transport Mode to TCP by passing rtsp transport flag to your python Script an be sure Port 554 is open

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to access rstp cam stream from a remote LAN with opencv. Doing so requires two basic computers, in my case rpi3s, one in each LAN.

Check both the rpis for IP forwarding being enabled:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

If the value is '0' then: edit /etc/sysctl.conf. Search for a line containing the entry #net.ipv4.ip_forward=1, and remove the # at the beginning of the line. Save the file and run the sysctl command to enable the edited setting:

```
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Setting up a serial vpn link between the two rpis with the following commands on the remote rpi.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ppp

sudo /usr/sbin/pppd updetach connect-delay 60000 noauth pty\
 "sudo -u myusername /usr/bin/ssh -t -t home_router_ip -l myusername -p myrouter_port_forwarded to ipcam's 554\
  sudo /usr/sbin/pppd noauth 192.168.186.2:192.168.186.1" 

sudo ip r add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ppp0
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then the following commands on the local rpi.

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev ppp0
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Finally following line in the python script of my original post must be changed to cam's local address, e.g. in my case:

```
x='rtsp://192.168.1.21/onvif1'
```